# fetch all data from mongodb collection

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch all data from my collection in mongodb using the following code

```
public function fetch_employee_list()
        {

            $m = new MongoClient();
            $db = $m->selectDB('fleet');
            $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'employee');
            // $name = array('Type' => 'name');
            $cursor = $collection->find();
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($cursor);
            exit;
         }
```

and the result I am getting is 
"MongoCursor  `Object()`"
but when i use

```
$cursor = $collection->findOne();
```

it gives me one result as array. 
what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    echo $obj . "\n";
}
```