# How to get entire MongoDB collection with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Using the following code, I can grab a node from a collection:

```
<?php

$user = "xxxx";
$pwd = 'xxxx';

if (isset($_POST['needleID'])) {
    $needleID = $_POST['needleID'];
} else {
    echo "needle ID not set";
}

//Manager Class
$connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://${user}:${pwd}@localhost:27017");

// Query Class
$filter = ['id'=> $needleID];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);

// Output of the executeQuery will be object of MongoDB\Driver\Cursor class
$rows = $connection->executeQuery('DBNAME.DBCOLLECTION', $query);

// Convert rows to Array and send result back to javascript as json
$rowsArr = $rows->toArray();
echo json_encode($rowsArr);

?>
```

However, what I'm really looking to do is get everything from the DBCOLLECTION.

I'm kind of at a loss on how to do this.  A few searches either go over my head or are for older versions of the PHP driver, such as this one  [fetch all data from mongodb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744469/fetch-all-data-from-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you query on a specific ID, then you will only receive the document with that ID as its value. If you want to retrieve all document in a collection, leave the filter empty, i.e. with `$filter = [];`.

Comment: I R Dum.  hah.  Thanks, makes perfect sense!

Comment: No problem. While you're here, I highly recommend you consider using the userland library for MongoDB: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library. It's not a necessity, but it wraps the functionality of the driver and makes querying simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) for exporting collections. On large collections your code will be slow and will timeout. Consider using pagination for results.

Comment: How large would it need to be before it's an issue?   I think the largest single collection will be about the equivalent of 1500 lines of text.